# rebasing interactively, but only one commit shows up?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a feature branch and made a commit earlier and pushed it to my fork.  Now I realized I should have done something in addition, so I made another change and committed it.

At this point I'd like to do an interactive rebase and squash those two commits together (and do a force push, no harm done in my case since I'm the only one using the branch) but when I run `git rebase -i` all that shows up in the listing is my most recent commit and not the one I pushed earlier.  How can I rebase on a commit I already pushed?

(Prior to making my second change I did run `git pull --rebase` from the origin's master branch, to get things up to date locally.  That's the branch I made the feature branch from.  Not sure if that caused trouble here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you do?

```
git rebase -i master
```

Comment: There, now I see them both (along with some from `master`).  Thank you.
Would you know what happened?